# Using XPath selectors with JQuery in Firebug

Tags: jquery, xpath, firebug

I'm trying to [use XPath selectors with JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#XPath_Selectors), but when I drop down to firebug (for example, in the linked page), I get syntax errors for the simplest XPath expressions:

```
>>> jQuery('//div')
"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: //div"
```

Am I doing something wrong, or are xpath selectors no longer supported?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xpath support was [dropped in jquery 1.2](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2). You can use [xpath plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/xpath) if you really need it.

Comment: Would be nice if the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#XPath_Selectors) reflected this...

Comment: @Louis the page you linked has a big reddish box saying it's an old api documentation and linking to the new one that doesn't have xpath selectors.

Answer (score 1):

XPath is not supported anymore. [xpath functions not supported in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558851/xpath-functions-not-supported-in-jquery) also talks about this.

To get all divs, use this:

```
>>> $('div')
```

or

```
>>> jQuery('div')
```

depending on your setup.